# Can I use the facebook feed dialog to post raw image data?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am generating a png using the html5 canvas element, so I have raw data in the form of a data:image url... Is it possible to use this data to post a picture to a facebook wall?

I'm assuming the answer is 'no', as I receive the following error:

> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the
>   application

It does upload the image, apparently, as I'm on a slow coffee-shop connection and can watch the upload percent slowly complete.

I'm using the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) because I'd prefer not to have a separate app that required auth...

Comment: can you provide the code that you are using to perform the post action?

Comment: you can always throw that data to a server, save it, and delete it upon retrieving by url.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a application on facebook developer portal you will be asked to give a url of your app, this means when you take data, such as pictures, json or whatnot, this domain name is allowed, if you enter www.me.com as your app domain and then create a url/picture for a feed submission you have to use the same url and not www.someoneelse.org because the sdk uses the app profile as reference. security checks and whatnot.